# Using # with Either types in PureScript

Tags: pipe, purescript, either

I like to use `#` to pass a value through several functions since it makes for more readable code:

```
1 # (\n -> n * 2) # (\n -> n + 1)
```

However, I would like do this with an `Either`:

```
(Right 1) ??? (\n -> n * 2) ??? (\n -> n + 1)
```

A `Right` value should be unpacked for each function, whereas a `Left` value should simply get passed through unchanged. In other words:

```
(Right x) ??? f == Right f(x)
(Left x)  ??? f == Left x
```

Is there already an operator for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `<#>` which is an operator alias for Functor's [mapFlipped](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/2.1.0/docs/Data.Functor#v:mapFlipped). The Functor instance for `Either` applies a function to the content of `Right`, but leaves `Left` values untouched.